# Python datetime print with timezone and dst

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a problem with python and timezones.

I have a date string like this:

```
2014-04-08T01:00:00+02:00
```

which I parse with dateutil.parse into a datetime object:

```
my_date = parser.parse(str(json)).replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('CET'))
```

this gives me a datetime obejct:

```
2014-04-08 01:00:00+02:00 with tzinfo = "Europe/Berlin" and _dst = 1:00:00
```

now I'd like to print a localized date format with:

```
my_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

unfortunately it returns:

```
'2014-04-08 01:00:00'
```

however it should be

```
'2014-04-08 00:00:00' in daylight saving time
```

Any ideas how to get the correct date?

Answer (score 0):

obviously there is a difference in the timezone/dst behaviour between

```
my_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

and

```
my_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

.replace does not regard the dst whereas .astimezone does.

Answer (score 0):

`2014-04-07 23:00:00 UTC` corresponds to `2014-04-08 01:00:00` in `Europe/Berlin` timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pytz
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = '2014-04-08T01:00:00+02:00'
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
dt = tz.normalize(parse(s).astimezone(tz))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
# -> 2014-04-08 01:00:00 CEST+0200
```

`2014-04-08 00:00:00` in `Europe/Berlin` corresponds to `2014-04-07 22:00:00 UTC`:

```
>>> tz.localize(parse('2014-04-08 00:00:00'), is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 7, 22, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```